# Click on a button and start Time counting on redirected page (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, django, redirect

I am trying to develop a quiz app with Django. Where I want to add a functionality like this - "When the users will click on start test button, they will be redirected to the questions page, and exam time will be started". Here I am using JavaScript "setInterval" to count time. It's working on the same page, but it's not working on the redirected page.

**My Js code :**

```
var check = null;

function printDuration() {
    if (check == null) {
        var cnt = 0;

        check = setInterval(function () {
            cnt += 1;
            document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = cnt;
        }, 1000);
    }
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(check);
    check = null;
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = '0';
}

console.log("Time counting... ... ...")
```

**Button**

```
<a href="{% url 'test' %}" class="btn btn-primary mt-5"id="btnStart" type="button" value="Start"
    onclick="printDuration();">Start Test</a>
```

**Redirected page code: , here time counting will be started:**

```
<h2 class="pb-5">Welcome to test page</h2>
    <p id="para">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the timer is on the page before redirect. When you go to a new url, everything reloads including the JavaScript. Everything from the previous page including your timer is removed. You'll have to make a new timer in the redirected page

Comment: ok, but how I will start that timer in the redirected page? The timer should be started that time, when the user will be redirected to that page.

Comment: The easiest way depending on your situation would be to have a button to start on the redirected page, have the code in the redirected page have its own timer that automatically starts, or have the main page create a new tab rather than redirect.